# Are the foursquare venue category icons used in the new WP7 app available for use in our client via the API?

Tags: windows-phone-7, foursquare

If they are available for use in our client, where can we find them?

Answer (score 2):

They're the same icons returned from foursquare with a bit of XAML magic to remove the borders.

This is how I was able to reproduce the effect (a special nod to Jeff Wilcox for the hint, he did it first with 4th & Mayor):

```
<Grid Width="150" Height="150">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid Opacity="0.40">
            <Image Width="100" Source="https://foursquare.com/img/categories/arts_entertainment/arcade_64.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <!-- create a border with same color as icon background and make borders large enough to cover the border of the icon in the lower right corner -->
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="60,60,10,10"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Microsoft Arcade" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP Black" Margin="5,0"/>
</Grid>
```